# Calculate GCD function is not working properly

Tags: javascript

When i display the image_width and image_height it display the image_width and image_height but when i display image_weight2 and image_height2 it display NaN instead of proper result.

I know there are lot of questions already on calculate GCD but here my question is why it is display NaN instead of number result.

```js
calculateGCD = (width, height) => {
    const image_width = width;
    const image_height = height;

    const gcd =
      image_height == 0
        ? image_width
        : this.calculateGCD(image_height, image_width % image_height);

    const image_width2 = image_width / gcd;
    const image_height2 = image_height / gcd;

    const aspect_ratio = `${image_width2} : ${image_height2}`;

    return aspect_ratio;
  };

console.log(calculateGCD(1200,627));
```

Comment: probably, because your function returns string and then you are trying to divide by string: `Math.round(image_width / gcd);`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten a string will be coerced to a number but this string is something like `"4 : 3"` so it will be equal to `NaN` when converted.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten I removed the Math.round function but it still arising the same NaN result. You can run my above snippet I edited it

Comment: @SouravSingh `Math.round` is irrelevant - you return a string that cannot be converted to a number, assign it to `gcd` and try to use it in a mathematical operation.

Comment: `console.log(gcd)` below `const gcd = ...` to see the issue more clearly

Answer (score 0):

As i see here the function is returning the `NAN : NAN` as a string , this is happening because of the recursion you are creating , thats ok to create recursion for finding the GCD , But if you calculate the aspect ratio outside of the function sepraely when you got the GCD value I think that will work , beacuse of the recursion stack the function is executed many time and for every time there is a change in the value of gcd. Or else you can clear me out with this , like why you want to calculate the aspect ratio inside `calculateGCD` function .

Or If i am right than you should try out like this

```
    const calculateGCD = (number1, number2) => {
    let gcd =
      number2 == 0
        ? number1
        : calculateGCD(number2, number1 % number2);

    return Promise.resolve(gcd);
  };

  getAspectRatio = (image_width , image_height) => {

      calculateGCD(image_width , image_height).then((gcd) => {
        const image_width2 = image_width / gcd;
        const image_height2 = image_height / gcd;

        const aspect_ratio = image_width2 +" : "+image_height2;
        console.log(aspect_ratio);

      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });   
  }

getAspectRation(1200,627);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using a promise here?

Comment: No such , but i want to show you that if you can calculate the aspect_ratio after the calculation of the gcd.

Answer (score 0):

NaN is occurring due to recursion calling of calculateGCD when the calculateGCD call again it change the image_width and image_height as well. So we need to declare width and height outside the function and calculate aspect ratio outside the function.

CalculateGDC function should be used only for calculate gcd instead of calculate aspect ratio with along.

```js
const width = 1600;
const height = 768;

calculateGCD = (width, height) => {
  const gcd =
    height == 0
      ? width
      : this.calculateGCD(height, width % height);

  return gcd;
};
  
const result = calculateGCD(width,height);
console.log(`${width/result} : ${height/result}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a string and you're trying to divide from a string. Try the following solution.

```js
function calculateGCD (a, b) {
    return (b == 0) ? a : calculateGCD (b, a%b);
}
var w = 1200;
var h = 3;
var r = calculateGCD (w, h);

console.log("Aspect     = ", w/r, ":", h/r);
```